# How to share dynamic title and description for link shared on facebook?

Tags: html, node.js

I am tring to share custom created link on facebook.Meta data tag is set it working fine when custom title and description set but when i try to dynamically change it then it is not working.

I tried it with angular js then also try with nodejs tring to render it from backend but no luck.

```
// my code for nodejs
reply.view(
  'metaData',
  { 
    title: 'My home page',
    description: 'this is test' 
  }
);

// html code
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{title}}" /> 
    <meta property="og:description" content ="{{description}}"/> 
  </head> 
  <body></body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use EJS instead of html for Node Application: -
You should use:-

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta property="og:title" content="<%= title %>" /> 
        <meta property="og:description" content ="<%= description %>"/> 
    </head> 
    <body></body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you share same link then facebook use cache 
  and 
  show same meta data.You have to make your uel dynamic.
  Example: http://riseToday.co?session_id=33454
  every share link id should be different.

```
<html> 
    <head> 
     <meta property="og:title" content="{{title}}" /> 
     <meta property="og:description" content ="{{description}}"/> 
     <meta property="og:image" 
     content="https://yourdomain/img/logo.png"/>
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="200" /> 
   </head> 
   <body></body> 
   </html>
```